# How to merge these codes, and move certain files instead of all files to a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The following code makes in each folder, that is placed in the same directory where the code is located, a folder named "VIDEO_TS".

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO mkdir "%%i"\VIDEO_TS
```

Like this:
D:\MOVIES
---------------\Bikini Spring Break
-----------------------------------------\P2HBSB5.jpg
-----------------------------------------\VTS_01_1.VOB
-----------------------------------------\VTS_02_0.BUP
-----------------------------------------\VTS_02_0.IFO
-----------------------------------------\VIDEO_TS
----------------\Breaking the Girls
----------------------------------------\pdnydtd.png
----------------------------------------\VTS_02_1.VOB
----------------------------------------\VTS_03_0.BUP
----------------------------------------\VTS_06_0.IFO
----------------------------------------\VIDEO_TS

And the following code puts all the files in each folder in it's "VIDEO_TS" folder.

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO MOVE "%%i"\*.* "%%i"\VIDEO_TS
```

My intention is to add both codes together.
And instead of all the files would be placed in their "VIDEO_TS" folder, only the following files in this folder should be moved to the "VIDEO_TS" folder: ".IFO",  ".BUP", and ".VOB".
I want to achieve this:
D:\MOVIES
---------------\Bikini Spring Break
----------------------------------------\P2HBSB5.jpg
----------------------------------------\VIDEO_TS
-------------------------------------------------------\VTS_01_1.VOB
-------------------------------------------------------\VTS_02_0.BUP
-------------------------------------------------------\VTS_02_0.IFO
----------------\Breaking the Girls
-----------------------------------------\pdnydtd.png
-----------------------------------------\VIDEO_TS
--------------------------------------------------------\VTS_02_1.VOB
--------------------------------------------------------\VTS_03_0.BUP
--------------------------------------------------------\VTS_06_0.IFO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i IN ('DIR /A:D /B') DO (
    mkdir "%%i"\VIDEO_TS
    FOR %%a IN (VOB BUP IFO) DO MOVE "%%i"\*.%%a "%%i"\VIDEO_TS
)
```